# User permission before accessing iPhone data

Tags: iphone, user-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ask permission to access Camera Roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572220/ask-permission-to-access-camera-roll)

I am creating a app compatible with iOS5 in xcode 4.3.2.
When i access photos, It is not showing permission alert also when i am running this app in iOS 6.0 devices. Can any one help me how to show permission alert for iOS6 devices.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572220/ask-permission-to-access-camera-roll

Comment: Thansks @rptwsthi.. It is working fine for me.

Comment: Most Welcome dear! But tryna look around. I found this solution on my first google result for ur question.. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep this thing in mind in future. But i had two questions for permission alert. One for access gallery and second for access contacts. Main thing is that i am unable to show permission alert in iOS6 device(For contacts) because my app is compatible with iOS5.

Comment: Another link for You!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6

Comment: It is not working. My app is closing with this issue  "implicit declaration of ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions is invalid in c99"

Answer (score 1):

you can show this by help of `ALAssetsLibrary` library & `ALAuthorizationStatus`

```
ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

    if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"permission alert message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```