# How to know if the app can access the photo album through UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum with iOS6

Tags: image, ios6, privacy

I want to know if my app can access the photo album when saving an image to the photo album. 
When the App is disabled in Privacy settings `didFinishSavingWithError` returns an error. How to detect if the app is allowed to access the photo album before saving the image?

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error != NULL)
    {
        // error        
    }
    else  
    {
        // No errors
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572220/ask-permission-to-access-camera-roll