# Photos Framework iOS 8 : change permission in settings app is not taken into account until I restart my app

Tags: ios, swift, photos

Here is the issue. I use Photos framework to authorize ask for access to the photo library via : `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization()`.

Then i do a switch on `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` to determine the authorization status. Everything works fine.

The problem is that I redirect the user to the settings app if the case is `.Denied` and when I flip the switch control "allow permissions" in the settings app to `.Authorized`, this change is taken into account only when the user restart the app. This not user very user friendly.

I have the same pattern for the local notifications permissions and it works perfectly.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this in the mean time?

Comment: Please take a look at 'Common Problem 2' section in my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595343/determine-if-the-access-to-photo-library-is-set-or-not-ios-8/38395022#38395022