# ios access to album, ok in ipad, not ok in iphones

Tags: ios, iphone

Our app needs to access user's album.
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription is already set in Info.plist.
Works ok in ipad mini 1(ios 9.3.5), promote access to user's album and can access to user's album.
But not ok in iphones(iphone 6,ios 10), does not promote needs access to album and can not open user's album.
And there is no such setting as access to album in setting -> privacy.
[image]

Here is our info.plist:
[image]

edit:
It is a bug in our app.
Setting a wrong app route. ImagePicker library does not work correctly. Nothing to do with this plist. Has been fixed

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I have attached the sreenshot of info.plist

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595343/determine-if-the-access-to-photo-library-is-set-or-not-phphotolibrary

Comment: Not exact the same, It does not promote anything and no such option in iphones.

Comment: It is a bug of our app, nothing to do with this plist. Has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in our app.
Setting a wrong app root.
ImagePicker library does not work correctly.
Nothing to do with this plist. Has been fixed