# How to get image name from UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset taken with library or camera?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get the file name from UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset in ios 11.0.3. unable to get picked image file name using this code. please help on this?

```
  if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset
                fileName = ((asset?.value(forKey: "filename")) as? String)!
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
                let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
                fileName = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: assets.firstObject!).first!.originalFilename
            }
```

Getting crashes on fileName = ((asset?.value(forKey: "filename")) as? String)!

Answer (score 5):

It seems like Apple has not added the new iOS 11 key to the info dictionary. Therefore the iOS 11 code will no work as it keeps returning nil. See this open radar http://www.openradar.me/34404703

Only solution I found so far is to use the iOS 10 code block even in iOS 11 and just ignore the `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` deprecated message (the key still exists and works in iOS 11)

Hope this helps

Comment: If you have access to read photos from the library (see `PHPhotoLibrary`), the value for this key should be non-null.

Comment: it is coming nil because you are not getting permission so first, you need to check PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(), if app has permission, it will return value.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this...

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as! PHAsset
                var resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)
                var orgFilename = (resources[0]).originalFilename
                print("File Name: ",orgFilename)
            }
```

Comment: 'UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset' has been renamed to 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset'

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the user's photo library, you'll be able to actually get the `PHAsset` value as expected from `UIImagePickerController`. It seems as though `UIImagePickerController` will not ask for permissions on your behalf so you'll need to do this yourself.

See [Determine if the access to photo library is set or not - PHPhotoLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595343/determine-if-the-access-to-photo-library-is-set-or-not-phphotolibrary) for a related discussion on how you may be able to check and ask for permissions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I will check it out tonight :)