# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum not getting completion callback

Tags: swift

I am running code `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)` to save a photo(which is a image from a URL) to the album library. This works perfectly. However, This is a blind function and I would like to call a callback to know if it saved successfully.

Here is what I am trying.

```
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(imageSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

            func imageSaved(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: AnyObject?) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    print("error")
                    print(error)
                    //Do Something with error associated with image
                } else {
                    // Everything is alright.
                }
            }
```

I am trying to work with this code here and I keep getting `Use of unresolved identifier imageSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)`

My problem is I don't understand the completion selector, and what is going on from Apple Documentation

`- (void)image:(UIImage *)image
    didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
                 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;`

What does that ^ mean? How do I work with that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(imageSaved(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: OH! Almost worked. Then the I try, here is what I get: does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -["AppName.FirebaseHelper methodSignatureForSelector:]
2018-02-20 06:46:43.445648-0800 "AppName"[7749:4189179] Unrecognized selector -AppName.FirebaseHelper methodSignatureForSelector:]

Comment: FYI, Idk if this helps, but I am testing to know what happens if the user didn't allow the app to access their photo albums. Then handle an error letting them know why they don't have the image.

Comment: @RyanB. Is this a `runtime` error or `compile time`?

Comment: It’s a runtime error when I click “download” and the functions get called

Comment: @RyanB. Then it's related to something else. Although if you want to check for the permissions [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595343/determine-if-the-access-to-photo-library-is-set-or-not-phphotolibrary) and after checking call your function

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue which I solved by making the class inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: actually, I tried every combination of the handlers i found in multiple threads and nothing worked until i tried the inherit from NSObject approach, and then, suddenly no error anymore -> +1
I have to say, that i used the call in a singleton, which had no inheritance before

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in **Apple's Documentation** here: [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(*:*:*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum)

> completionSelector
>   The method selector of the completionTarget object to call. This optional method **should conform to the following signature**:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image
    didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
                 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

So your callback function in Swift must be something like

```
@objc func imageSaved(image:UIImage,didFinishSavingWithError error:Error,contextInfo:UnsafeMutableRawPointer?){
        self.showAlert(title:"Image saved to Photos!", message: "");
    }
```