# Detect permission of media library ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, media-library

In my app, I want to detect that if user give the permission to his media library or not. User may denied media library permission when system popup ask or later from setting. Is there any way to detect the status of media library permission?

Here is my code that access list of songs.

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *songArray = [everything items];
```

Please see below screenshot where user can change Media Library permissions.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ask permission to access Camera Roll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572220/ask-permission-to-access-camera-roll)

Comment: @rptwsthi, please read question carefully permission from camera roll and media player is not same.

Comment: You mentioned media library in your question not player. Plus check accepted answer to the question that should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13572568/656600

Comment: @rptwsthi, Please install any app in your device who access your media library(music files) and camera roll too. And then open setting you will get know these both are different permission.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
-(void) checkMediaLibraryPermissions {
    [MPMediaLibrary requestAuthorization:^(MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus status){
        switch (status) {
            case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
                // not determined
                break;
            }
            case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusRestricted: {
                // restricted
                break;
            }
            case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusDenied: {
                // denied
                break;
            }
            case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: {
                // authorized
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary is for access your photo and videos, when i ran above code it asks permissions for camera roll. My question is about permission for media library(music files).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Can you please post your code in objective-C.

Comment: @ajay_nasa I updated, I didnt use xcode so let me know if it doesnt compile

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily, i solved my problem by checking `songArray` object in below code

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]; 
NSArray *songArray = [everything items];
```

If, user denied permission then `songArray` object is always nil, but if user allows permission to access to `Media Library` then `songArray` object have array of songs. Even if there will be no songs in device but user give permission to access `Media Library` then there will be array with 0 count.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** access check. The simple solution is as follows, and you can alter to include the other alternatives however in my case it was all access or nothing.

```
private func checkPermissionForMusic() -> Bool {
    switch MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorized:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Caution about using the above solutions - they do perform as a block statement and do not return a value (`return true` or `return "authorised"`) on the same thread; the result is handled on a background thread. If you decide to use the suggestions above, use a handler (call another function) to handle the result you're expecting. This solution on the other hand tells you immediately if you have access or not. No waiting required.

More info is available in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary/1621282-authorizationstatus)

Comment: Man I wish people would comment why they vote a solution down. This looks good to me, now I'm unsure if this will work or not or what the issue might be.